# Get Around AVAudioEngine Latency?

Tags: avfoundation, latency, avaudioengine

I am using a `tap` to get PCM buffer samples  in a block-based callback within the `AVAudioEngine` API.  I was previously using Core-Audio but the complexity and insurmountable mountain of poorly documented c code drove me to this AVFoundation based framework.

I have code like this:

```
 [self startEngine];

  [_player play];


[mainMixer installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:256 format:[mainMixer outputFormatForBus:0] block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when) {

          [buffer setFrameLength:256];



          float * const  p = *(buffer.floatChannelData);

          float sum = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < buffer.frameLength; i+=buffer.stride) {
             if (p[i] > sum) {
                sum = p[i];
             }
          }
```

I am simply kicking off a drum loop and capturing the highest valued float within each callback.  Elsewhere, there is a a visual component that animates in concert with the changing value of the max(`sum`) I'm taking.

The problem is that the animation of the view and the drum loop I am hearing is almost a second out of sync.  So my question is whether or not `AVAudioEngine` is fundamentally incapable of providing callbacks that are within even 50-100ms of the audio source time?